# Cordova iOS app not showing iOS7 simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5

I am new to Cordova(PhoneGap) progamming. I have created a app following the command-line interface. When I opened iOs app by clicking on **.xcodeproj** file, It only show iOS6 simulator in **active schemes** dropdown. I want it to run on iOS7 also. How to add support for iOS7 in this case.

Note : I'am using XCode 5.1 & have worked with it previously. But when I opened this project, there are no iOS7 simulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your xcode version

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: set your deployment target as 7.0 or 7.1. if you are using xCode 5/5.1

XCode 5 comes with iOS 7 sdk and simulator automatically. However, since iOS 7 is not supported in old xcode version 4.6 and the below. so for if you doesn't have new version of xcode. install xcode 5.1 because it support iOS 7.1 and 7.0 simulator

Comment: I have Xcode 5.1 & have devoloped projects in it. I know the fact you mentioned. But now for this purticular project & can't get iOS7 simulator.

Comment: iOS 7 only comes in iphone 3.5 and 4 inch screen because those only have retina display @rohanAM